# Kitura iOS Application User Authentication mongodb

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

My current application is running on parse server and I would like to port it to Kitura. So far I have managed to connect to the mongodb that is running behind Parse Server and serve data.

For the web part I have managed to make http basic authentication work, using a static dictionary with userids and password.

I am struggling with the iOS part. My application already has a lot of users. Users are stored in a table in mongodb. There I have three types of users:

- Facebook users. Users that signed up using their Facebook accounts.
- Direct users. Users that used the sign up form of the app to create an account.
- Anonymous users. For them I am generating a unique id that I store in their device, so I can persist their data. For the context of this question they should be treated as direct users.

To migrate users from parse server to kitura, I plan to take the following steps:

1. On first app start. Create a random key and store it in the user table.
2. Once saved, use this key to login to Kitura.
3. On successful login to Kitura delete the key.

I have installed Mobile Access Client and Push Notification.

What I cannot solve is what method to use to authenticate users, both server and client side.

So far basic http authentication works (direct users only), but I believe there is a better way.

My Current basic http authentication

```
let url = "http://172.20.10.3:8080/private2/class/KiteSpot?responseType=json"
var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: nsURL)
mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
let loginString = "<user>:<pass>"
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
mutableURLRequest.addValue("DirectUserToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-token-type")
mutableURLRequest.addValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
mutableURLRequest.addValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
self.sendRequest(mutableURLRequest, onSuccess: onSuccess, onFailure: onFailure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication over SSL is a reasonable and simplistic solution but [has a few shortcomings](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https#990).

**Mobile Client Access** implements the OAuth2 protocol which uses a token granting strategy which is a little more secure because you aren't sending your users' raw credentials across the network on every request. MCA supports Facebook, Google, and Custom authentication schemes. The main advantage of MCA/OAuth2 is if your clients need to be granted access to several other servers or third parties, those parties will only need a token (with expiration rules) to authenticate. ([Good article for getting started with MCA.](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/07/protect-web-apps-with-mobile-client-access/))

Depending on your what your application does will impact what you decide to choose for an authentication scheme.

---

Also, I'm not sure how you are storing the usernames and passwords in the database, but I would recommend [salting + hashing](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) if your aren't already to ensure your users are safe if your database ever becomes compromised.

Comment: I have already setup Mobile Client Access. I am currently trying to work out the custom identity provider, where I can check the user and password against my database. But cannot find details on how to accomplish that. What are the end points that should be called on client side and what events will that trigger on the server.

Comment: Going through this may help: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-mca-custom-identity-provider-sample

Comment: I have already go through the above example and converted it to swift. But startAuthorization and handleChallengeAnswer is never called, when I request a private url from the mobile side. I should probably create a middleware for it, but I cannot find instruction on how to create it. It could be the case that kitura is not ready for this yet.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-mca-kitura-credentials-plugin

Comment: yes but not in a development phase. For the moment I am using basic http authentication and I am following the link you sent me. Once out of development I am will move from basic auth to mca.